# How to connect multiple select tag in HTML?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a data grid containing the student's information (**Name**, **Class**, **Score**) with a checkbox for each row. The requirement is when the user selects a Node or multiple Nodes and clicks on the show information Button it opens a new window that contains **3 drop-down lists**: The first one, shows all the Student's Name, the Second one shows all the student's Class and the third one shows all the student's Score. Everything is ok I want just to connect the 3 drop-down lists. I want when I click on the Name of the first student, the second and the third drop-down list to show the information of the first student without selecting them manually.
This is my HTML code

```
<ng-template #studentInformationTemplate>
...
<div class= "row" style="margin-right: 40px">
   <div class="col form-group" id="StudentNameDiv">
         <label class= control-label" for=studentName"> Student Name </label>
         <select class="form-control input control id="StudentName" name="StudentName">
             <option *ngFor="let name of NameStudentTable" [value]="name">{{ name }} </option>
         </select>
   </div>


   <div class="col form-group" id="StudentClassDiv">
         <label class= control-label" for=studentClass"> Student Class</label>
         <select class="form-control input control id="StudentClass" name="StudentClass">
             <option *ngFor="let class of NameClassTable" [value]="class"> {{ class}} </option>
         </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class= "row" style="margin-right: 40px">
   <div class="col form-group" id="StudentNameDiv">
         <label class= control-label" for=studentScore"> Student Score</label>
         <select class="form-control input control id="StudentClass" name="StudentScore">
             <option *ngFor="let score of NameScoreTable" [value]="score "> {{ score }} </option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: There are errors in your code. 1. `margin-right /40px` the `/` should be a `:`. 2. Your option tag is closed by a `</select>`.

Comment: Thanks. It was by mistake when copying the code I correct them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you will need to use `change` event of the `select`. Everytime you select a new name, it will call `onNameChanged` function. Within this function, you can get the newly selected value, and do some logic to update the `select` on the student class.

You will also need to use `ngModel` that allow you to update the value of the `select` for the student class. We will bind the `selectedClass` to this `ngModel` so you can update it in the `onNameChanged` function.

#### example.component.html

```html
...

<select id="StudentName" (change)="onNameChanged($event)">
 <option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{name}}</option>
</select>

<select id="StudentClass" [(ngModel)]="selectedClass">
  <option *ngFor="let class of classes [value]="class">{{class}}</option>
</select>

...
```

#### example.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  public selectedClass = '';

  ...

  public onNameChanged(event: Event) {

    const selectElement = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    
    // this will have the newly selected student name.
    const selectedName = selectElement.value;

    // Now you do your logic to get the class belongs to this student.
    const studentClass = '';    

    // Then update the selectedClass with it.
    this.selectedClass = studentClass;
  }

  ...
}
```

If you have trouble with `ngModel`, you will need to import `FormsModule` in `AppModule` to use it.

#### app.module.ts

```js
...
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ...
    FormsModule, 
    ...
  ],
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried it but the **studentClass** becomes empty

Comment: @InfJhoanny Did you add your own logic to get the correct `studentClass`? OR you just copy and paste the `const studentClass = ''`?

Comment: Yes and I have the values in the drop-down list and when I select the studentName it changes the value of the studentClass but the values are  just hidden

Comment: the labels of the studentClass arre hidden

Comment: @InfJhoanny Did you make sure that the value of the `studentClass` actually belong to the `classes` array option used in the `*ngFor` in the HTML?

Comment: @InfJhoanny If the `public classes = ['A', 'B'] `. Then `studentClass` must be `const studentClass = 'A'` OR `const studentClass = 'B'`. If you have `const studentClass = 'C'`, it will not show up in the UI. That because the `select` doesn't have `C` as the option.